# Counting rows based upon conditional grouping with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
        position_time telematic_trip_no  lat_dec lon_dec
1 2016-06-05 00:00:01         526132109 -26.6641 27.8733
2 2016-06-05 00:00:01         526028387 -26.6402 27.8059
3 2016-06-05 00:00:01         526081476 -26.5545 28.3263
4 2016-06-05 00:00:04         526140512 -26.5310 27.8704
5 2016-06-05 00:00:05         526140518 -26.5310 27.8704
6 2016-06-05 00:00:19         526006880 -26.5010 27.8490 
  is_stolen hour_of_day time_of_day day_of_week  lat_min
1         0           0           0      Sunday -26.6651
2         0           0           0      Sunday -26.6412
3         0           0           0      Sunday -26.5555
4         0           0           0      Sunday -26.5320
5         0           0           0      Sunday -26.5320
6         0           0           0      Sunday -26.5020
   lat_max lon_max lon_min 
1 -26.6631 27.8743 27.8723     
2 -26.6392 27.8069 27.8049    
3 -26.5535 28.3273 28.3253    
4 -26.5300 27.8714 27.8694      
5 -26.5300 27.8714 27.8694      
6 -26.5000 27.8500 27.8480
```

Now what I want to do is count for each line where *is_stolen* = 1, the number of rows in the dataframe that fulfill the following conditions:

- the *lat_dec* and *lon_dec* are between the *lat_max*, *lat_min*, *lon_max* and *lon_min* (i.e. fit within the 'box' around that GPS point)
- the *time_of_day* and *day_of_week* are the same as that of the row of interest
- the *telematic_trip_no* of the rows need to be different to that of the row of interest
- and finally the *is_stolen* tag of the matching rows needs to be equal to 0

I've written a script to do this using a **for** loop but it ran *very* slowly and it got me thinking if there's an efficient way to do complex row counts with many conditions using something like dplyr or data.table?

ps If you're curious I am indeed trying to calculate how many cars a stolen-car passes during a typical trip :)

Comment: `dput()` of enough data that includes the necessary conditions wld help others help you.

Comment: Can you also include your "for loop" code that didn't work?

Comment: What does "the row of interest" refer to? Do you select one row then compare it with all the other rows?

Comment: Try using a `which()` statement to create a subset of the rows in which all of your conditions are met. That way it iterates through the data set only once pulling out the appropriate data. You may need a sequence of two to four statements to keep in human readable and compact, but it is usually faster and less error-prone than a complicated loop. here is the Cran description. http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/which

Answer (score 1):

Given your description of the problem, the following should work

```
library(dplyr)
library(stats)
# df is the data.frame (see below)
df <- cbind(ID=seq_len(nrow(df)),df)
r.stolen <- which(df$is_stolen == 1)
r.not <- which(df$is_stolen != 1)
print(df[rep(r.not, times=length(r.stolen)),] %>%
  setNames(.,paste0(names(.),"_not")) %>%
    bind_cols(df[rep(r.stolen, each=length(r.not)),], .) %>% 
      mutate(in_range = as.numeric(telematic_trip_no != telematic_trip_no_not & time_of_day == time_of_day_not & day_of_week == day_of_week_not & lat_dec >= lat_min_not & lat_dec <= lat_max_not & lon_dec >= lon_min_not & lon_dec <= lon_max_not)) %>%
        group_by(ID) %>%
          summarise(count = sum(in_range)) %>% 
            arrange(desc(count)))
```

The first line just adds a column named `ID` to `df` that identifies the row by its row number that we can later `dplyr::group_by` to make the count.

The next two lines divides the rows into stolen and not-stolen cars. The key is to:

1. replicate each row of stolen cars `N` times where `N` is the number of not-stolen car rows,
2. replicate the rows of not-stolen cars (as a block) `M` times where `M` is the number of stolen car rows, and
3. append the result of (2) to (1) as new columns and change the names of these new columns so that we can reference them in the condition

The result of (3) have rows that enumerates all pairs of stolen and not-stolen rows from the original data frame so that your condition can be applied in an array fashion. The `dplyr` piped R workflow that is the fourth line of the code (wrapped in a `print()`) does this:

- the first command replicates the not-stolen car rows using `times`
- the second command appends `_not` to the column names to distinguish them from the stolen car columns when we bind the columns. Thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29948876/adding-prefix-or-suffix-to-most-data-frame-variable-names-in-piped-r-workflow) for that gem.
- the third command replicates the stolen car rows using `each` and appends the previous result as new columns using `dplyr::bind_cols`
- the fourth command uses `dplyr::mutate` to create a new column named `in_range` that is the result of applying the condition. The boolean result is converted to `{0,1}` to allow for easy accumulation
- the rest of the commands in the pipe does the counting of `in_range` grouped by the `ID` and arranging the results in decreasing order of the count. Note that now `ID` is the column that identifies the rows of the original data frame for which `is_stolen = 1` whereas `ID_not` is the column for rows that `is_stolen = 0`

This assumes that you want the count for each row that `is_stolen = 1` in the original data frame, which is what you said in your question. If instead you really want the count for each `telematic_trip_no` that is stolen, then you can use

```
group_by(telematic_trip_no) %>%
```

in the pipe instead.

I've tested this using the following data snippet

```
df <- structure(list(position_time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("2016-06-05 00:00:01", 
                "2016-06-05 00:00:04", "2016-06-05 00:00:05", "2016-06-05 00:00:19", 
                "2016-06-05 00:00:20", "2016-06-05 00:00:22", "2016-06-05 00:00:23", 
                "2016-06-05 00:00:35", "2016-06-05 00:09:34", "2016-06-06 01:00:06"
                ), class = "factor"), telematic_trip_no = c(526132109L, 526028387L, 
                526081476L, 526140512L, 526140518L, 526006880L, 526017880L, 526027880L, 
                526006880L, 526006890L, 526106880L, 526005880L, 526007880L), 
                lat_dec = c(-26.6641, -26.6402, -26.5545, -26.531, -26.531, 
                -26.501, -26.5315, -26.5325, -26.501, -26.5315, -26.5007, 
                -26.5315, -26.5315), lon_dec = c(27.8733, 27.8059, 28.3263, 
                27.8704, 27.8704, 27.849, 27.88, 27.87, 27.849, 27.87, 27.8493, 
                27.87, 27.87), is_stolen = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
                1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), hour_of_day = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), time_of_day = c(0L, 
                0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 0L), day_of_week = structure(c(2L, 
                2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Monday", 
                "Sunday"), class = "factor"), lat_min = c(-26.6651, -26.6412, 
                -26.5555, -26.532, -26.532, -26.502, -26.532, -26.532, -26.502, 
                -26.532, -26.502, -26.532, -26.532), lat_max = c(-26.6631, 
                -26.6392, -26.5535, -26.53, -26.53, -26.5, -26.53, -26.53, 
                -26.5, -26.53, -26.5, -26.53, -26.53), lon_max = c(27.8743, 
                27.8069, 28.3273, 27.8714, 27.8714, 27.85, 27.8714, 27.8714, 
                27.85, 27.8714, 27.85, 27.8714, 27.8714), lon_min = c(27.8723, 
                27.8049, 28.3253, 27.8694, 27.8694, 27.848, 27.8694, 27.8694, 
                27.848, 27.8694, 27.848, 27.8694, 27.8694)), .Names = c("position_time", 
                "telematic_trip_no", "lat_dec", "lon_dec", "is_stolen", "hour_of_day", 
                "time_of_day", "day_of_week", "lat_min", "lat_max", "lon_max", 
                "lon_min"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Here, I appended `7` new rows with `is_stolen = 1` to your original `6` rows that are all `is_stolen = 0`:

1. the first added row with `telematic_trip_no = 526005880` violates the longitude condition for all not-stolen rows, so its count should be `0`
2. the second added row with `telematic_trip_no = 526006880` violates the latitude condition for all not-stolen rows, so its count should be `0`
3. the third added row with `telematic_trip_no = 526007880` violates the `telematic_trip_no` condition for all not-stolen rows, so its count should be `0`
4. the fourth added row with `telematic_trip_no = 526006890` satisfies the condition for rows `4` and `5` that are not-stolen, so its count should be `2`
5. the fifth added row with `telematic_trip_no = 526106880` satisfies the condition for row `6` that is not-stolen, so its count should be `1`
6. the sixth added row with `telematic_trip_no = 526017880` violates the `time_of_day` condition for all not-stolen rows, so its count should be `0`
7. the seventh added row with `telematic_trip_no = 526027880` violates the `day_of_week` condition for all not-stolen rows, so its count should be `0`

Running the code on this data gives:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
     ID count
  <int> <dbl>
1    10     2
2    11     1
3     7     0
4     8     0
5     9     0
6    12     0
7    13     0
```

which is as expected recalling that the appended rows with `is_stolen = 1` starts at row `7` with `ID = 7`.

If one were to group by `telematic_trip_no` instead, we get the result:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  telematic_trip_no count
              <int> <dbl>
1         526006890     2
2         526106880     1
3         526005880     0
4         526006880     0
5         526007880     0
6         526017880     0
7         526027880     0
```

As a caveat, the above approach does cost memory. Worst case the number of rows  grows to `N^2/4` where `N` is the number of rows in the original data frame, and the number of columns doubles for the data frame that is used to evaluate the condition. As with most array processing techniques, there is a trade between speed and memory.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

[The current development version of data.table, v1.9.7](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) has a new feature *non-equi* joins, which makes conditional joins quite straightforward. Using @aichao's data:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
setDT(df)[, ID := .I] # add row numbers
not_stolen = df[is_stolen == 0L]
is_stolen  = df[is_stolen == 1L]

not_stolen[is_stolen, 
    .(ID = i.ID, N = .N - sum(telematic_trip_no == i.telematic_trip_no)), 
    on = .(time_of_day, day_of_week, lat_min <= lat_dec, 
          lat_max >= lat_dec, lon_min <= lon_dec, lon_max >= lon_dec), 
    by=.EACHI][, .(ID, N)]
#    ID  N
# 1:  7 NA
# 2:  8 NA
# 3:  9  0
# 4: 10  2
# 5: 11  1
# 6: 12 NA
# 7: 13 NA
```

The part `not_stolen[is_stolen,` performs a *subset-like* join operation.. i.e., for each row in `is_stolen`, matching *row indices* (based on condition provided to `on=` argument) is extracted.

`by = .EACHI` ensures that, for each row in `i` (first) argument, here `is_stolen`, on the corresponding matching row indices, the expression provided in `j`, the second argument, `.(ID = i.ID, N = .N-sum(telematic_trip_no==i.telematic_trip_no)),` is evaluated. That returns the result shown above.

HTH.

Comment: I was looking for a function for joins like that. Good to know. Thanks.