# make column names for only the 4th to 723rd colums prefixed with "distance"

Tags: r

Here is my code:

`colnames(sheet1)[4:723] <- colnames(sheet1[,4:723],do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "distance")`

It did not show any error message.

What I want are column names in the pattern of "distance 1" "distance 2" ... "distance 719" "distance 720"

However, what I got were still the default names  "Col4"   "Col5"   "Col6"   "Col7"   "Col8"   "Col9"   "Col10"  "Col11"  "Col12" ...

Can someone help me with it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `colnames(sheet1)[4:723] <- paste0('distance_', colnames(sheet1)[4:723])`

Comment: In addition to ^^ on why setting prefix isn't working, several SO posts deal with pasting column names on a subset of columns, such as https://stackoverflow.com/q/48566857/5325862

Comment: @utubun thank you for your answer but it seems that the output is  "distance_Col4"   "distance_Col5"   "distance_Col6"   "distance_Col7".....

Comment: @camille thank you for your help! It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `sheet1` already has column names, we can replace the wanted slice of them with:

```
colnames(sheet1)[4:723] = colnames(matrix(ncol=720), F, "distance ")
```