# How to Create R Object Using Object Reference from Function

Tags: r, function

I am trying to create an object from an object that is being referenced from my function in R.

Here is an example:

```
test_function <- function(mydata, mydata2, newobject){

mydata2 <- mydata %>%
select(
data,
variable_newobject = someothervariable)
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output and why is mydata2 an argument?

Comment: i want to have mydata$variable to mydata2$variable_newobject

Comment: I found this post be helpful and will close this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29948876/adding-prefix-or-suffix-to-most-data-frame-variable-names-in-piped-r-workflow